# Rails: is twitter typeahead conflicts client side validation?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, client-side-validation, twitter-typeahead

I am using [client side validation](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations)(v3.0.13) gem in my rails(v3.0.20) app. Recently I added [twitter's typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/)(v0.10.2) for auto suggest.

I have a model named Insurance and the column 'name' is mandatory. When I submit a form with these two js files loaded, I get javascript error **Cannot read property 'presence' of undefined** in browser console. After this error, other javascript code is failed to run, for example If I put a alert in form submit function, its not working.

Model

insurance.rb

```
    class Insurance < ActiveRecord::Base
        validates :name, :presence =>  { :message => "Must be filled" }
    end
```

form.html.erb

```
    <%= javascript_include_tag "rails.validations", "typeahead" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "typeahead"%>

    <%= form_for @insurance, :validate => true, :html => {:id => 'insurance_form', :class=>"form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
    <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :name, :class=>"control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
            <%= f.text_field :name, :class =>"input-medium typeahead" %>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <% end %>
```

And my javascript code

```
    var insurance_names = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];

    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
      return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substringRegex;
        matches = [];
        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
        $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
          if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
            matches.push({ value: str });
          }
        });     
        cb(matches);
      };
    };

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'insurance_names',
      displayKey: 'value',
      source: substringMatcher(insurance_names)
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function($e, datum){
        $(this).trigger('change');
    });
```

If I comment the model validation code and then submit the form, then there is no javascript error. 
And also without this typeahead.js client side validation is working fine.

Here's the POST request that fires when I submit the form:

```
Started POST "/insurances" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-28 18:31:53 +0530 Processing by InsurancesController#create as HTML Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "insurance"=>{"insurance_name"=>"", "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create insurance"}....Rendered insurances/new.html.erb within layouts/nhs-full (209.4ms) Completed 200 OK in 8333ms (Views: 218.3ms | ActiveRecord: 84.5ms)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the sever log when you make the POST request that is triggered when you submit the form?

Comment: @NickM Server log is **Started POST "/insurances" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-28 18:31:53 +0530
  Processing by InsurancesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "insurance"=>{"insurance_name"=>"", "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create insurance"}....Rendered insurances/new.html.erb within layouts/nhs-full (209.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8333ms (Views: 218.3ms | ActiveRecord: 84.5ms)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with validations. If you take a look at your sever log, you'll notice that both name and description are being passed in as empty strings.

Guessing your problem is coming from these lines:

```
}).on('typeahead:selected', function($e, datum){
    $(this).trigger('change');
});
```

If the typeahead is actually working (showing partial matches when you type), the issue is that the string that option you ultimately pick isn't being added to the value of the name/description inputs. I'm guessing that if you type in a random string that there are no matches for it will work fine, or at least it will pass the name a d or description params.

May not be the answer you were looking for, but at least you know that your problem has nothing to do with ActiveRecord validations.